# The problem of changes to a table with several different events (RabbitMQ) in a service and in ASP Core

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

The problem is that when a service receives messages from several other services and wants to apply those changes to a table, can this simultaneous change not cause a problem ?

To be more precise, the problem is that when a service receives two different messages from two different queues and wants to apply those received changes to the database, this synchronization will probably cause a problem !

Suppose a message contains updated user information and a message from another queue related to another case where these changes or updates are to be applied to Mongo ( assuming these changes occur at the same time or with a little distance ) . If the database is making changes to the `author` information, the information about the `term` collection must be updated at the same time or in a few moments later .

The table information for this service is as follows :

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think you understood my question correctly

I'm talking about microservice architecture and the use of non-relational tables

Comment: Hi, @Hasan Karami Moheb, are you talking about the [concurrency](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/) of MongoDB? Please detail more info about the scenarios of your requirement and the specific problem.

Comment: Thankful . Yes, almost (or exactly) .

I put more explanations in my questions and put a picture to better understand the subject .

I hope I was able to raise the issue correctly . Although I do not know why the photo was not uploaded!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deal with **Concurrency Conflict**, this usually comes in two flavors:

1. Pessimistic concurrency control

**Pessimistic, or negative, concurrency control** is when a record is locked at the time the user begins his or her edit process.  In this concurrency mode, the record remains locked for the duration of the edit.  The primary advantage is that no other user is able to get a lock on the record for updating, effectively informing any requesting user that they cannot update the record because it is in use.

There are several drawbacks to pessimistic concurrency control.  If the user goes for a coffee break, the record remains locked, denying anyone else the ability to update the record, even if it has been untouched by the initial requestor.  Also, in order to maintain record locks, a persistent connection to the database server is required.  Since web applications can have hundreds or thousands of simultaneous users, a persistent connection to the database cannot be maintained without having tremendous resources on the database server.  Moreover, some database tools are licensed based on the number of concurrent connections.  As such, applications that use pessimistic concurrency would require additional licenses for use.

2. Optimistic concurrency control

**Optimistic Concurrency** means we allow concurrency conflicts happen. But we also (want to) believe that it will not happen. And if it happens anyway, we react on it in some manner. It’s supported in Entity Framework – you have got concurrency exceptions to handle, you can add a column of row version type (or timestamp) to database table and so on… It’s probably a good moment to stop and come back to the subject in separate post!

Frameworks such as Entity Framework have optimistic concurrency control built in (although it may be turned off). It’s instructive to quickly see how it works. Basically there are three steps:

1. Get an entity from the DB and disconnect.
2. Edit in memory.
3. Update the db with changes using a special update clause. Something
   like: “Update this row WHERE the current values are same as original
   values”.

There are some useful articles to help u with Optimistic concurrency control.

[OPTIMISTIC CONCURRENCY IN MONGODB USING .NET AND C#](https://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2013/04/08/optimistic-concurrency-in-mongodb-using-net-and-csharp/)
[Document-Level Optimistic Concurrency in MongoDB](https://jimmybogard.com/document-level-optimistic-concurrency-in-mongodb/)

I use [Transactions](https://alexalvess.medium.com/getting-started-with-net-core-api-mongodb-and-transactions-c7a021684d01) for concurrent updates. Query with ID before updating operation.

Comment: Thankful . Thanks for putting in the time to answer .

The answer was right and good .

Shame I have a low score and I can not confirm your answer .